# Init my Angular 6 project fails : schematics does not works

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-schematics

I'm trying to create a new angular project and add the `@angular/material` schematics. But it fails with this error :

```
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Your project is not using the default configuration for build and test. The Angular Material schematics can only be used with the default configuration
```

To create my project and add the material schematics from scratch I done the following commands :

```
nvm use v10.10.0
npm install -g @angular/cli # Version is : @angular/cli@6.2.1
npm install -g @angular-devkit/schematics-cli # Version is : @angular-devkit/schematics-cli@0.8.1
ng new a
cd a
ng add @angular/material # -> Error here
```

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: Keep eyes of this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12230) logged in Angular CLI repo

Comment: Till then you can use [this workaround](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11438#issuecomment-419430197)

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar. So for now, what is the best way for me to install a stable version of Angular ?

Comment: I have seen this workaround but I don't find projects.YOUR-APP-NAME.targets in my projects

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is already logged in github, you can keep eye on the same using [#12230](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12230).

But till then it is resolved, you can use below work around you have to tweak `angular.json` a bit

**Change**

> projects.YOUR-APP-NAME.targets

**To**

> projects.YOUR-APP-NAME.architect

Find below explanation to see where exactly change needs to be made in `angular.json`

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "sample-bank": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "targets": { //< -- change `targets` to `architect`
        ....
      },
      ...
  }
}
```